# Does Revelation 20:14 implicitly indicate that the Sea also will be cast into the lake of fire?

Tags: revelation

Revelation 20:13,14 (KJV);

> 13. And **the sea** gave up the dead which were in it; and **death and hell** delivered up the dead which were in them: and they were judged every man according to their works.
> 14. And **death and hell** were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.

It may be considered that (the Sea) means (the Beast of the Sea.)

So, in verse 14 of chapter 20, may it implicitly indicate that the sea, i.e: the Beast of the Sea, will, also, be cast into the lake of fire?

It seems to me that this interpretation is acceptable. Look Revelation 21:1 (KJV);

> 1. And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away; **and there was no more sea.**

It seems to me that the Beast of the Sea is the most dangerous among the three devilish beings mentioned in Revelation.

Comment: Stop misusing the hermeneutical-approaches tag. You're just asking about the interpretation of specific verbs, not about how to apply or compare various hermeneutical approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does Revelation 20:14 implicitly indicate that the Sea also will be cast into the lake of fire?**

In short to your question, the answer is No.

Revelation 20:13,14 (KJV);

> 13 "And the sea gave up the dead which were in it; and **death and hell**
>   delivered up the dead which were in them: and they were judged every
>   man according to their works. 14 And death and hell were cast into the
>   lake of fire. This is the second death."

Revelation 20:14  (NET Bible)

> 14 "Then  **Death and Hades** were thrown into the lake of fire. This is
>   the second death—the lake of fire."

Hundreds of thousands of people, perhaps millions have died in the sea, in shipwrecks, storms, and battles in ships  e.t.c. and whose bodies have never been recovered and given a burial on land. And so in the resurrection of the dead, Revelation 20:13 says that not only death and Hades/hell gave up those that are dead in them but also the sea gave up those in it. At John 5:28-29 Jesus said that those in the memorial tombs will hear his voice and come out to "resurrection". The fact that Revelation 20:13 mentions the "sea" is a more inclusive statement than that of Jesus.

Those who are dead in Hades/hell are not in the same place as those in the watery sea. That is why Revelation 20:14  says that death and Hades/hell are thrown into the lake of fire, but not the sea, this is so because the sea in a literal sense will never cease to exist on the earth. The sea plays an important role in the earth's weather and the water cycle, if the sea were to cease to exist,  life on earth will also cease to exist. (Ecclesiastes 1:7, Amos 5:5)

If the literal sea were thrown into the "lake of fire" the fire will be put out and cease to exist rather than the sea. The book of Revelation is quite clear that the lake of fire will never cease to exist. In his vision, John states:

Revelation 20:10 (NASB)

> 10 "And the devil who deceived them was thrown into **the lake of fire**
>   and [a]brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are also; and
>   **they will be tormented day and night forever and ever."**

In verse 21:1 the word  "sea" is a metaphor and refers to the wicked and restless mankind alienated from God, Isaiah 57:20 states, **" But the wicked are like the tossing sea,  For it cannot be quiet, And its waters toss up refuse and mud."(NASB)**

The turbulent "sea" of wicked, rebellious mankind will cease to exist. In its place will be “a new heaven and a new earth" (Read 2 Peter 3:13)​

Revelation 21:1  (NASB)

> 21 Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth; for the first heaven and
>   the first earth passed away, and there is no longer any sea.

Lake of Fire.

The "lake of fire" is symbolic for it is said that death and Hades/hell are thrown into it, both are intangible things and neither is affected by the fire. Furthermore, the Devil, a spirit creature is also thrown into the lake of fire, spirit creatures cannot be hurt by literal fire. (Rev. 19:20)

Revelation 19:20  (NASB)

> 20 "And the beast was seized and with him the false prophet who
>   performed the signs [a]in his presence, by which he deceived those who
>   had received the mark of the beast and those who worshiped his image;
>   these two were thrown alive into the lake of fire which burns with
>   [b]brimstone."

Comment: how the Sea in Revelation 20:13 is literal, while in Revelation 21:1 is metaphorical?!, Why not in both verses the Sea is metaphorical?

Comment: salah; The answer is lengthy and I am trying to use a chat room to answer you, can you help ?

Comment: God promises that his creation of the earth and the sea will remain forever, Eccl. 1:2-9, so when you read that "the sea is no more", by this you understand that it is a metaphor/illustrative use. For example at Rev. 17:1, 15.Rev. verses20: 13,14  must be understood in a literal sense, and so do not contradict other verses in the scriptures.  Compare  Acts 10:42, Isaiah  25:8, 1 Cor. 15:26 and Rev. 2:22,20:6 ,21:8  If the sea is metaphorical, then all the verse is also metaphorical, this will contradict other similar verses.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The "sea" is a metaphor.  God defined His metaphors in the scriptures, especially within the OT prophesies.  The sea was a metaphor for the pagan nations, the gentiles which surrounded the "pleasant land" or the "earth" of Israel much as water surrounds an island.

> *"“‘I thought how I would set you among my sons, and give you a pleasant land, a heritage most beauteous of all nations. And I thought you would call me, My Father, and would not turn from following me."*  (Jer. 3:19, RSV)
>
> *"“and I scattered them with a whirlwind among all the nations which they had not known. Thus the land they left was desolate, so that no one went to and fro, and the pleasant land was made desolate.”* (Zech. 7:14, RSV)

In prophetic judgment language each nation was "the earth" the prophet was sent to warn of coming judgment.  Moses said, speaking to the OT congregation of Israel,

> *"Give ear, O ye heavens, and I will speak; and hear, O earth, the words of my mouth."* (Deu. 32:1, KJV)

where the "heavens" were the political ruling authorities and the "earth" were the people of that land nation under that authority.

Speaking of the coming judgment against Judah and Jerusalem, Isaiah 1:1-2,

> *"The vision of Isaiah the son of Amoz, which he saw **concerning Judah and Jerusalem** in the days of Uzziah, Jotham, Ahaz, and Hezekiah, kings of Judah.*
>
> *2 Hear, O heavens, and give ear, O earth: for the Lord hath spoken, I have nourished and brought up children, and they have rebelled against me."*  (KJV)

was again calling the ruling authorities "heavens" and the people of the land nation of Judah "O earth".

So, in prophesy, judgment language is associated with specific land nations, and must be kept in context with the particular land nation the prophet was sent to warn.  Revelation was the warning of the destruction of Jerusalem, and the Mosaic temple, for all those that had pierced Christ (Rev. 1:7).

So, the "earth" of that prophesy was Judea and Jerusalem; the "heavens" of that prophesy were the ruling authorities over that land territory which foremost were the Sanhedrin in Jerusalem, the scribes and Pharisees; and subsequently their ruling authority whom they answered to - the Romans.  As Judea was a conquered territory under Roman rule, attached to the empirical province of Syria since 63 BC, then the "earth" of Judea was surrounded by the pagan nations "sea" of Rome.

The sea beast was the Roman ruler, Caesar; and by extension Caesar's dominion or kingdom of Rome.  The land beast was the Sanhedrin who plotted to kill Christ.  In prophesy, wild beasts (wolves, lions, leopards, bears) were always the symbols and metaphors of tyrannical rulers who parasitically fed off the wealth of the people. (1) (2)

> *"7 Therefore, ye shepherds, hear the word of the Lord;*
>
> *8 As I live, saith the Lord God, **surely because my flock became a prey**, and my flock became meat to every beast of the field, because there was no shepherd, neither did my shepherds search for my flock, but the shepherds fed themselves, and fed not my flock;*
>
> *9 Therefore, O ye shepherds, hear the word of the Lord;*
>
> *10 Thus saith the Lord God; Behold, I am against the shepherds; and I will require my flock at their hand, and cause them to cease from feeding the flock; neither shall the shepherds feed themselves any more; for I will deliver my flock from their mouth, that they may not be meat for them."*  (Ezek. 34:7-10, KJV)

The shepherds set over the flock - the Levitical priests - were supposed to care for the people of God, but instead began confiscating their wealth, and destroying the people.  God compared them to wolves who kill and eat the sheep (Ezek. 22:7; Zeph. 3:3; Matt. 7:15)

Once the Mosaic temple was destroyed, the animal sacrifices ceased, then all nations were welcome to come to the heavenly Jerusalem of the everlasting, heavenly kingdom of God.  Christ became that sacrificial lamb for all people of all nations to be able to have the opportunity to be reconciled to the Father.  Thus, no more sea - as our Father no longer makes a distinction between land nations or land territories.

> *"26 For ye are all the children of God by faith in Christ Jesus. 27 For as many of you as have been baptized into Christ have put on Christ.*
>
> *28 There is neither Jew nor Greek, there is neither bond nor free, there is neither male nor female: for ye are all one in Christ Jesus.*
>
> *29 And if ye be Christ's, then are ye Abraham's seed, and heirs according to the promise."*  (Gal. 3:26-29, KJV)

As all those who are in Christ are counted for the seed of Abraham, it is no longer a blood line distinction, but a faith line that counts.  And, as those who are counted for the seed of Abraham are God's definition of Israel (3), then all those in Christ are the Israel of God who are saved with an everlasting salvation (Isa. 45:17).

Therefore, all nations are welcome to the Feast of Tabernacles, the Feast of the nations, and there is no more distinction between land nations - so no more "sea".  The first heaven and the first earth referred to the Mosaic covenant.  The new heaven and the new earth refers to the new covenant under the gospel of Christ. (4)

Further reading:  The Lake of Fire at [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/11/16/the-lake-of-fire/)

Notes:

1) The Signs of Revelation - Part V: The Animal Symbols... at [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/03/16/the-signs-of-revelation-part-v-the-animal-symbols-of-the-battle/)

2) The Beast of Revelation - [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/09/01/the-beast-of-revelation/)

3) God's Definitions - Part I: The House of Israel [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/01/15/gods-definitions-part-i-the-house-of-israel/)

4) The Signs of Revelation - Part VIII: The New Heavens and The New Earth [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/04/06/the-signs-of-revelation-part-viii-the-new-heavens-and-new-earth/)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to me that the Beast of the Sea is the most dangerous among
>   the three devilish beings mentioned in Revelation.

More dangerous than Satan? No way.

The beast of the sea is already in the lake of fire in Revelation 19, before the events of Revelation 20 take place. The dead coming from the Sea has nothing to do with the Revelation 13:1 beast from the sea nor is this related to the sea no longer existing in Revelation 21. The sea was not cast into the lake of fire. It simply ceases to exist but we are not told why or how this happens.

Answer (score 0):

The dead bodies/those that died there (presumably without God being preached to them) are brought up from the literal sea, as mentioned above, and just expands on what Jesus said about the resurrection being to Everybody. The literal sea goes away with the former earth and the former Heavens when there is no longer a need for them in the new Heaven. Weather has nothing to do with it anymore, and the new earth is the new 'Garden of Eden' where everything lives in peace (was it is mentioned a place where children lay with lions and sheep in peace, etc.

The 'Lake/sea of Fire' can't be quenched by any amount of water, even if you poured the entirety of all the oceans on all the planets and moons into it. It's Holly Fire made by God for the sole purpose of torment for evil. No 'Heavens', no stars, no anything other than each evil in their own ocean of Fire and brimstone suffering. (If they can see others in the distance isn't clear but would certainly be another horror to know they are there with those they followed, but i think personally the torment of the flames and 'endless drowning in waves of it' would be far more than enough to keep them distracted from even seeing others right next to them).

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).